# How to iterate through a folder and change the file-ending in a bat file?

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a folder full of images called FILENAME.jpg.tif

This happened after I converted the format but forgot that the old file ending is part of the file name.

How could I write a bat file which removes the .jpg so that the new name would be FILENAME.tif?

Thanks for any help,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your folder only contains FILENAME.jpg.tif's, this should work:

```
ren *.tif *.
ren *.jpg *.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell much?

```
get-childitem * -include *.jpg.tif | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '\.jpg\.tif','.tif' }
```